# Can not login with correct username and password

Tags: login, wp-login-form

I can not access to Wordpress dashboard with correct username and password. If I give any wrong password it's not showing any error message for the wrong. When I press on Log in button then the same page is (wp-login page) appearing. 
I've tried by deleting browser caches, cookies and replaced the old wp-login.php file with a fresh wp-login.php file. But it's still not working. 
If I reinstall the Wordpress on the domain the same trouble is appearing. 
I don't know where is the main problem for that. How can I solve this problem.

Comment: In my case, the problem was a database that was full. New inserts were denied, so no new tokens could be generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried many methods but anyone couldn't worked for me. So tried to solve by myself. I've discovered a solution. 
First, I cleared Browsing Data (cookie, cache and others) by pressing Ctrl+Shift+Delete. 
Secondly, Exit from the browser.
Third Step, Disconnect the internet connection.
Fourth Step, Clean my PC using a cleaner software (I used wise care 360).
Sixth, Connect the internet and successfully access to Wordpress dashboard.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few things you can try. One of them you have already tried.

**Clear your browser cache** (which you have stated you have tried), just make sure you cleared everything, cookies and cache.

**Try deactivating all plugins** by either logging in via `SSH` or `FTP` to your server and rename `wp-content/plugins` to `wp-content/plugins_backup`.

**Change wp theme**, it maybe an issue with your current theme. Try changing to one of the defaults like `twentyfifteen`.

**.htaccess** could be causing problems so you can once again `SSH` or `FTP` to your server and rename `.htaccess` to `htaccess.backup`.

**Also check your wp-config.php** making sure that your site url is defined properly, eg:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me. It requires specific knowledge of PHPMYAdmin and wp_config.php

1. Open your MySQL database in PHPMyAdmin
2. Go to your wp-config.php file
3. In wp-config, find this line: $table_prefix = 'your_prefix'; change 'your_prefix' to something new, for example 'your_new_prefix'.
4. Visit any page on your site. Wordpress will start a new installation process. It will create a whole new set of database tables. During installation, type in your CURRENT user name and password.
5. In PHPMyAdmin, open your [your_new_prefix]_users table, copy your password hash from the user_pass column.
6. Open your your_prefix_users (i.e. the old) table. Find your user and paste the password hash you have copied to its user_pass column.
7. In wp_config, type in your previous prefix. Now you should be able to log in properly.
8. Delete temporary tables from your database.

Takes like 3 minutes. Especially helpful if you don't get your password recovery emails for some reason. Warning: some of the steps can not be undone. Back up before you do anything.

Comment: That's a lot of work just to generate a password. You have several online wordpress password generators like https://www.useotools.com/wordpress-password-hash-generator or https://codebeautify.org/wordpress-password-hash-generator

Comment: Thanks Hibbem. I don't remember why I did it this way back then. I guess your comment can be helpful to people with similar problems, so I think it would be great if you could turn it into an answer.

Comment: I wanted to do this, but I don't have enough points..